# Erro ao tentar atualizar registro com Spring MVC

Tags: java-ee, spring-mvc

Boa tarde devs... estou estudandod spring mvc, em meu sistema tenho um controler que possui um metodo mapeado como @getmappint(/buscar/{id}), conforme abaixo:

```
@GetMapping("buscar/{id}")
public ModelAndView alterarPrestador(@PathVariable ("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
    PrestadorModel user = new PrestadorDao().getPrestador(id);
    model.addAttribute("PrestadorModel", user);
    //model.addAttribute("atualizar", true);
    ModelAndView visao = new ModelAndView("alterar", model);

    return visao;
}
```

ele retorna um modelandview, que é a pagina JSP alterar. ate ai blz, ele preenche os campos do formulario com as informações corretas.
esse e o formulario:

```
<body>
<h4>Alterar dados de prestaddor</h4>
<form:form modelAttribute="PrestadorModel" action="update"
    method="post">
    <div>

        <div>
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:label path="pisPasep">PIS/PASEP:</form:label>
            <form:input path="pisPasep" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="nome">Nome completo:</form:label>
            <form:input path="nome" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">

    </div>
</form:form>
```

ao enviar os dados por este formulario, para o metodo atualizar(), ele diz que o metodo POST não é suportado, esse e o metodo que recebe os dados da alterar.jsp

```
@PostMapping("update")
public ModelAndView atualizar(@ModelAttribute("PrestadorModel") PrestadorModel prestador, ModelMap model){
    PrestadorDao dao = new PrestadorDao();
    dao.atualizarPrestador(prestador);
    //model.addAttribute("msg", "Dados atualizados com sucesso!!");

    return new ModelAndView("listaprestador");
}
```

espero a ajuda de vcs.

Answer (score 0):

A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte, no meu formulario lista.jsp

```
<h2>Prestadores cadastrados</h2>
<hr>

<div>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>CODIGO</td>
                <td>NOME</td>
                <td>PIS/PASEP</td>
            </tr>

        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <c:forEach var="prestador" items="${listaPrestador }">
                <tr>
                    <td>${prestador.id }</td>
                    <td>${prestador.nome }</td>
                    <td>${prestador.pisPasep }</td>
                    <td><a href="buscar?id=${prestador.id }">Alterar</a><img></td>
                    <td><a href="excluir">Excluir</a><img></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

no controler, o metodo que faz a leitura do id na base de dados:

```
    @GetMapping("buscar")
public ModelAndView teste(PrestadorModel prestador, ModelMap model) {

    PrestadorDao dao = new PrestadorDao();
    PrestadorModel prest = dao.getPrestador(prestador.getId());
    model.addAttribute("PrestadorModel", prest);
    return new ModelAndView("alterar");
}
```

A pagina alterar.jsp, que ira mostrar os dados recuperados com o id fornecido:

```
<body>
<h4>Alterar dados de prestaddor</h4>
<form:form modelAttribute="PrestadorModel" action="atualizar"
    method="post">
    <div>

        <div>
            <form:hidden path="id" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <form:label path="pisPasep">PIS/PASEP:</form:label>
            <form:input path="pisPasep" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <form:label path="nome">Nome completo:</form:label>
            <form:input path="nome" />
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Atualizar">

    </div>
</form:form>
```

E no controler, quando o usuario enviar apartir da pagina alterar.jsp os dados para atualizar:

```
@PostMapping("atualizar")
public ModelAndView atualizar(@ModelAttribute("PrestadorModel") PrestadorModel prestador, ModelMap model){
    PrestadorDao dao = new PrestadorDao();
    dao.atualizarPrestador(prestador);
    //model.addAttribute("msg", "Dados atualizados com sucesso!!");

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/prestador/listaprestador");
}
```